# Download ZIP file of private GitHub repository using `wget` like `curl`

Tags: curl, wget, zip, github

There are already some questions with answers how to download the ZIP file of GitHub repositories, but they don't work if the repository is private.

I know it *should* work with `wget` somehow since it does work with `curl`:

```
curl -u <USER> -L -o <FILENAME> https://github.com/<USER>/<REPO>/archive/master.zip
```

The above line will ask for `<USER>`'s password, download the master branch ZIP file and save it as `<FILENAME>`. However, the `wget` equivalent doesn't work:

```
wget --user=<USER> --ask-password --output-document=<FILENAME> https://github.com/<USER>/<REPO>/archive/master.zip
```

Results in `ERROR 404: Not Found.`

Comment: Does adding `--auth-no-challenge` help?

Comment: Probably curl always sends the auth. However IMHO github is not behaving correctly by giving a 404 when not authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that github.com is not behaving politely by saying that the resource does not exist when a non-authenticated GET request is made. Normally `wget` will first try requesting the resource without authentication, and retry with that authentication data when a 401 Not Authenticated error is given.

This can be worked around by passing `--auth-no-challenge` so that `wget` sends the authentication data the first time.